# Como agrego un emoji selector que escriba en mi input segun el emoji seleccionado?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Ayuda plox
Estoy haciendo un blog php y no funcionan los emojis de android por eso quiero que en un extremo del input name="content" aparezca un emoji selector tipo Facebook:
Este es mi formulario:

```html
 <form action="new.php" method="POST">
  <h1 class="tituloSubir">Sube tu Tema</h1>
<div class="form__group field">
  <input type="input" class="form__field" placeholder="Tu nombre" name="author" id='author' required />
  <label for="name" class="form__label">Tu nombre</label>
</div>
<br>
<div class="form__group field">
  <input type="text" class="form__field" placeholder="Título" name="title" id='title' required />
  <label class="form__label">Título</label>
</div>
<br>
<div class="form__group field">
  <input type="text" class="form__field" placeholder="Contenido" name="content" id='content' required/>

  <label class="form__label">Contenido</label>
</div>
<input type="file" name="upload" value="Subir">
<br>
 <button type="submit">Subir</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías buscar algún plugin para jquery que te acomode para tu proyecto, no es tan difícil, puedes buscar [aquí](https://plugins.jquery.com/)

```js
$("#content").emojioneArea({
  pickerPosition: "bottom"
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form__group field">
  <textarea type="text" class="form__field" placeholder="Contenido" name="content" id='content' required> </textarea>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.js"></script>
```

Comment: Graaciaaaaaaaaas! En serio me ayudaste muchísimo! :´)